How to configure Jersey to use micrometer
I am new to Jersey and was exploring how to use Micrometer with Jersey.
I am following https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/reference/jetty.html
Goal

How can /metrics endpoint come up?

How can I have an existing endpoint configured to be counted as some configuration?
@Path("sample")
public class Sample {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {

    }
}



Found some code snippet here but could not understand where to plugin below code.
Can someone please review and suggest.
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.register(new MetricsApplicationEventListener(
                registry,
                new DefaultJerseyTagsProvider(),
                "http.server.requests",
                true));
ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);

I did try adding a SimpleApplicationEventListener and registering above but it doesn't work.

Micrometer support is in Jersey now. See the documentation.
